# Владелец таблицы на хостинге и локале, как поменять маппинг Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp

Возникла необходимость добавить новые таблицы в бд, но встала проблема. При развертывании бд восстанавливалась из дампа и владелец таблиц - [dbo] - также как и на локальном. При создании таблицы(делаю через ssms) владельцем становится учетная запись от админки и маппинг слетает, таблицу не находит, поскольку на локале - dbo. Маппинг для entity формирую автоматически средствами студии. Подскажите как поменять владельца таблицы в маппинге(это наверное часть имени)
Пересоздавать бд, перезаливать данные и т.д. - очевидно и долго.

Comment: `При создании таблицы(делаю через ssms) ` так может при работе в ssms от правильного владельца создать таблицы, а не колдовать в ef?

Comment: что значит от правильного? хостинг выдает аккаунт, а не я. На локале у меня юзер dbo и схема dbo, а на хостинге я не имею прав для настройки. Правда я уже решил проблему, у аккаунта оказалось есть права для изменения схемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ALTER SCHEMA dbo 
    TRANSFER [u0658305_admin].[pekLog]